# In Shopify, how do I append an ID to Pagination URLs?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'd like to append an id to my paginated url so that my blog comments scroll down to the comments section when pagination is clicked.

This is the current code.  How can I add a liquid append condition to update the urls?

```
{{ paginate | default_pagination: previous: previous_label, next: next_label | replace: 'view=ajax', '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once Shopify does it's thing and takes your customer to the correct new page in the pagination effort, there is nothing stopping you from running a little JS code and migrating to some ID in the HTML, like for example, the comments. You can use localStorage or a cookie for that.

There is no need to mess with Liquid and URL's for custom things like this. Use the JS.

Comment: That's a bad approach. There should easily be a way to do this in liquid.

Comment: Because you should try to reduce your javascript as much as possible.  There is no need for it.  It should be rendered in liquid on page load.

Comment: That is pure nonsense. JS was made for this purpose, and the one-line code to do what you want won't hurt a fly. Clearly Shopify has decided allowing people to tack on their little ditties is not in their best interest, so you have no choice but to use JS. 

Who told you to reduce JS anyway? Clearly, one can abuse JS and pay the price, but for your needs here, it is the perfect tool for the job at hand. I guess learning to distinguish when to use a tool remains a challenge.